How to upload excel file to Azure blob storage immediately after after preparing it without saving it locally?
I am using Java, Azure SDK and Apache POI. My requirement is to prepare an excel using Apache POI and upload the same to Azure blob storage. but however I should not store the excel file locally before uploading it. Any solution?

After searching over internet, I found that CloudBlockBlob.openOutputStream() can be used in combination with ByteArrayOutputStream to upload the excel file without saving it locally.
The following piece of code can give an idea:
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// write ByteArrayOutputStream to work book
workbook.write(baos);
// get destination cloud blob directory for the archive
CloudBlobDirectory destCloudBlobDirectory = container
    .getDirectoryReference("Some Directory");

// get destination cloud block blob with reference to the source blob
CloudBlockBlob destCloudBlockBlob = destCloudBlobDirectory
    .getBlockBlobReference("fileName");

// open blob output stream
BlobOutputStream blobOutputStream = destCloudBlockBlob.openOutputStream();

destCloudBlockBlob.getProperties().setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

